# Performance between IQueryable<> & List<>, why list is faster?

Tags: entity-framework, list, t-sql, sql-server-2012, iqueryable

I'm using entityframework and I've got 2 models:

- GeographyBoundary
- CountryISO3166

My goal is to get the distinct CountryISO3166 Id in the table GeographyBoundary.

I've parsed the data from the db with my dataContext (db) and I've tried to get the data using **IQueryable** first:

```
IQueryable<Int64> listCountryId = db.GeographyBoundary
    .Select(x => x.CountryId).Distinct();
IQueryable<CountryISO3166> results = db.CountryISO3166
    .Where(x=> listCountryId.Any(y=> y == x.Id));

foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Result countryId: " + result.Name_en);
}
```

then I did the same with **List**:

```
List<Int64> listCountryId = db.GeographyBoundary
    .Select(x => x.CountryId).Distinct();
List<CountryISO3166> results = db.CountryISO3166
    .Where(x=> listCountryId.Any(y=> y == x.Id));

foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Result countryId: " + result.Name_en);
}
```

Data from SQL Profiler when calling db with **IQueryable**

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name_en] AS [Name_en], 
    [Extent1].[Name_fr] AS [Name_fr], 
    [Extent1].[ISO3166_1_alpha_2] AS [ISO3166_1_alpha_2], 
    [Extent1].[ISO3166_1_alpha_3] AS [ISO3166_1_alpha_3], 
    [Extent1].[ISO3166_1_numeric] AS [ISO3166_1_numeric], 
    [Extent1].[Itu] AS [Itu], 
    [Extent1].[Marc] AS [Marc], 
    [Extent1].[Wmo] AS [Wmo], 
    [Extent1].[Ds] AS [Ds], 
    [Extent1].[Dial] AS [Dial], 
    [Extent1].[Fifa] AS [Fifa], 
    [Extent1].[Fips] AS [Fips], 
    [Extent1].[Gaul] AS [Gaul], 
    [Extent1].[Ioc] AS [Ioc], 
    [Extent1].[CurrencyAlphabeticCode] AS [CurrencyAlphabeticCode], 
    [Extent1].[CurrencyCountryName] AS [CurrencyCountryName], 
    [Extent1].[CurrencyMinorUnit] AS [CurrencyMinorUnit], 
    [Extent1].[CurrencyName] AS [CurrencyName], 
    [Extent1].[CurrencyNumericCode] AS [CurrencyNumericCode], 
    [Extent1].[IsIndependent] AS [IsIndependent]
    FROM [dbo].[CountryISO3166] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent2].[CountryId] AS [CountryId]
            FROM [dbo].[GeographyBoundary] AS [Extent2]
        )  AS [Distinct1]
        WHERE [Distinct1].[CountryId] = [Extent1].[Id]
    )
```

Data from SQL Profiler when calling db with **List**

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name_en] AS [Name_en], 
    [Extent1].[Name_fr] AS [Name_fr], 
    [Extent1].[ISO3166_1_alpha_2] AS [ISO3166_1_alpha_2], 
    [Extent1].[ISO3166_1_alpha_3] AS [ISO3166_1_alpha_3], 
    [Extent1].[ISO3166_1_numeric] AS [ISO3166_1_numeric], 
    [Extent1].[Itu] AS [Itu], 
    [Extent1].[Marc] AS [Marc], 
    [Extent1].[Wmo] AS [Wmo], 
    [Extent1].[Ds] AS [Ds], 
    [Extent1].[Dial] AS [Dial], 
    [Extent1].[Fifa] AS [Fifa], 
    [Extent1].[Fips] AS [Fips], 
    [Extent1].[Gaul] AS [Gaul], 
    [Extent1].[Ioc] AS [Ioc], 
    [Extent1].[CurrencyAlphabeticCode] AS [CurrencyAlphabeticCode], 
    [Extent1].[CurrencyCountryName] AS [CurrencyCountryName], 
    [Extent1].[CurrencyMinorUnit] AS [CurrencyMinorUnit], 
    [Extent1].[CurrencyName] AS [CurrencyName], 
    [Extent1].[CurrencyNumericCode] AS [CurrencyNumericCode], 
    [Extent1].[IsIndependent] AS [IsIndependent]
    FROM [dbo].[CountryISO3166] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  (SELECT 
            cast(2 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(5 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(10 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable3]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(13 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable4]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(14 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable5]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(20 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable6]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(21 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable7]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(26 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable8]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(28 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable9]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(29 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable10]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(31 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable11]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(34 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable12]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(39 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable13]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(45 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable14]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(54 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable15]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(58 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable16]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(60 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable17]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(69 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable18]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(74 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable19]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(75 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable20]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(82 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable21]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(84 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable22]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(85 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable23]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(100 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable24]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(101 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable25]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(102 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable26]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(106 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable27]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(109 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable28]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(111 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable29]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(114 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable30]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(117 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable31]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(118 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable32]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(122 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable33]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(127 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable34]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(128 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable35]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(129 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable36]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(131 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable37]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(137 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable38]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(143 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable39]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(145 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable40]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(146 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable41]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(148 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable42]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(156 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable43]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(158 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable44]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(161 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable45]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(165 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable46]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(167 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable47]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(173 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable48]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(174 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable49]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(176 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable50]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(177 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable51]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(180 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable52]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(181 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable53]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(192 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable54]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(196 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable55]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(199 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable56]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(201 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable57]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(202 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable58]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(205 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable59]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(208 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable60]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(214 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable61]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(215 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable62]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(217 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable63]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(220 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable64]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(227 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable65]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(232 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable66]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(234 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable67]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(235 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable68]) AS [UnionAll67]
        WHERE [UnionAll67].[C1] = [Extent1].[Id]
    )
```

The result is that:

- using **IQueryable** the response from the server took **10 seconds**.
- using **List** the response from the server took less than **1 second**.

Why is this happening?

Shouldn't be IQueryable faster?

Comment: no, it isn't. You access the objects one by one in foreach. As you can see in the SQL, you call the database with each of the records, so you have n queries to do. With ToList(), all is loaded into memory, so only one query+db call.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed but in both cases (IQueryable and List ) I get 1 db call

Comment: What it seems is that, when using List the querying is done by the database, while with IQueryable all the computation of the query is done by the application. Still, this is what it seems but I might be wrong.

Comment: Actually, your `List` version has 2 DB calls: 1 to get the distinct `CountryId`s and the 2nd to get the final results.  I suspect the real answer will involve looking at the query plans for the first query.

Comment: There are 2 calls to the DB in both cases(list & IQueryable), if in the second call I pass a IQueryable<Int64> listCountryId, the response from the server will be 10sec. In all the other 3 cases the response is less than 1 sec.

Comment: You should try removing the `.Distinct()` in the IQueryable scenario. I guess it prevents SQL query optimizer doing its job correctly